# Get pixel data from iText Image

Tags: java, image, pdf, image-processing, itext

I'm trying to compare the first page of many PDFs to see if the first page is a "cover page" or not. I have one PDF that I'm considering the "control" that I know has a cover page. I want to loop over each PDF and compare its first page to the first page of my control PDF. Since the underlying data varies between PDFs even if the page *looks* the same to the human eye, I want to compare the pages pixel-by-pixel. I'll run a few tests and determine a difference percentage threshold.

#### How do I get the RGB values of the individual pixels of an iText Image?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(new Document(), outputStream);
// get first page
PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
// get the first page as an image
Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
PdfGraphics2D graphics = new PdfGraphics2D(image.getTemplateData(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
// how do I loop over all pixels in the image?
```

Comment: This is quite simple with [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), which I've actually implemented instead of iText in this case, but I still wonder how to inspect image pixels from iText.

Comment: Pixels make sense in the context of bitmap images. PDFs are no bitmap images (they may contain bitmap images but don't need to). Even an iText `Image` may contain either bitmap or vector graphics. Thus, your question as is does not make sense. Furthermore, why do you assume RGB pixels? PDFs can use a large selection of colour spaces.

Comment: @mkl - I'm converting the first page into an image (like exporting the first page to a JPG), and I want to compare the RGB values of each pixel in that image to the RGB values from another image of the same size to see what percent of the pixels match.

Comment: iText does not support rendering PDFs to bitmap images. At least not out of the box, even though it should be possible to implement such rendering on top of the parser framework.